# How do you use nested for loops to make triangles in c++

Tags: c++

Here's what I have:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i <= height; i++) {
    for (int s = 0; s < height; s++) {
        cout << "*" << endl;
    }
}
```

It prints out a list of asterisks like this:

```
*
*
*
*
```

Answer (score 2):

You're outputting a newline after every *single* character. You only want to do that in the outer loop, after each *line* of characters.

In addition, using a fixed value for the width will result in a square rather than a triangle. You should therefore base your inner loop on `i` rather than `height`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main (void) {
    int height = 7;
    for (int i = 1 ; i <= height; i++) {
        for (int s = 0; s < i; s++)
            cout << "*";
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output of that is the very triangular:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
```

---

Of course, that will *work* but it's hardly embracing the essence of the C++ language.

What you *really* have there is C code but using C++ output methods, something that will get you quickly labeled as a C+ programmer :-)

Although I wouldn't hand this in as a beginner assignment, it will at least force you to think about using the added facilities of the C++ language going forward:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main (void) {
    int height = 7;
    string s(height, '*');
    for (int i = 1 ; i <= height; i++)
        cout << s.substr(0,i) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

That thinking will convince you at some point to discard character arrays for strings (or arrays in general for vectors, or many other similar decisions), something that will make your programming *much* faster and safer in future.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
int main()
{
int height =10;

for (int i = 0 ; i <= height; i++) {
    for (int s = 0; s < i; s++) {
        cout << "*";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
}
```

Comment: It's usually a bit more helpful if you explain things as well, instead of just giving some code.